# What is the "truly-the" function?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

In SBCL 2.0.1, `(macroexpand '(dolist (x '(1 2 3)) (princ x)))` returns:

```lisp
(BLOCK NIL
  (LET ((#:N-LIST385 '(1 2 3)))
    (TAGBODY
     #:START386
      (UNLESS (ENDP #:N-LIST385)
        (LET ((X (TRULY-THE (MEMBER 3 2 1) (CAR #:N-LIST385))))
          (SETQ #:N-LIST385 (CDR #:N-LIST385))
          (TAGBODY (PRINC X)))
        (GO #:START386))))
  NIL)
T
```

What is `TRULY-THE`? It appears to be non-standard because I could not find it in the Common Lisp HyperSpec.

What is the difference between `TRULY-THE` and `THE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the SBCL [manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#index-truly_002dthe):

> Special Operator: **truly-the** *[sb-ext] value-type form*

> Specifies that the values returned by form conform to the value-type, and causes the compiler to trust this information unconditionally.

> Consequences are undefined if any result is not of the declared type -- typical symptoms including memory corruptions. Use with great care.

In other words, the `the` operator in certain cases (for instance with a high level of debugging) compiles to a test to check the correctness of the type specified, while `truly-the` instructs the compiler to NEVER perform this check.

Comment: What is the practical use of `truly-the`?

Comment: I think there is no practical use for this beyond compiler-writing (the manual says clearly: "In short: don’t use it.") Or perhaps it could be used for documenting parts of a program in which you are more than certain that a variable will have a certain value.

Comment: `truly-the` helps the compiler know the type of an expression, which helps type inference and code generation

Comment: @coredump, you are right!